# Working with composite primary key in django project with legacy database

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, composite-primary-key, legacy-database

I have a legacy database, where some table contains composite primary key. The model I get by running `manage.py inspectdb` command looks like this.

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    field1_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='field1id', primary_key=True)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(db_column='isfavorite', default=False, null=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(db_column='isadmin', default=False, null=False)
    role = models.IntegerField(default=USER_GUEST, null=False)
    field2 = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    field3 = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(db_column='isactive', null=False, default=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='userid', primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mytable'
        unique_together = (('user', 'field1_id'),)
```

I can fetch data normally. However, the problem arises when I want to run `save()` command on some model instance. The query django executes is not correct one. For example:

```
>>> from web_services.apps.my_app.models import MyTable
>>> g = MyTable.objects.get(field1_id=12)
>>> g.is_active = True
>>> g.save()
>>> connection.queries[-1]
{'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'UPDATE `mytable` SET `isfavorite` = 0, `isadmin` = 1, `role` = 3, `field2` = 1, `field3` = 1, `isactive` = 1 WHERE `mytable`.`field1id` = 12'}
```

But I need:

```
{'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'UPDATE `mytable` SET `isfavorite` = 0, `isadmin` = 1, `role` = 3, `field2` = 1, `field3` = 1, `isactive` = 1 WHERE `mytable`.`field1id` = 12' AND `mytable`.`userid` = 1'}
```

Since django does not support composite primary key, what would be the best solution to overcome that problem? Note, it's legacy database table and it didn't have `AutoField`.

**EDIT: adds legacy table structure**

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userid     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field1id   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| isfavorite | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| isadmin    | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| role       | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field2     | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| field3     | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| isactive   | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | 1       |       |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: It would be best if you add the table structure as well.

Comment: @e4c5 added legacy table structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately django does [not yet have a composite primary key](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) (composite primary keys are also called multi column primary keys)

There is a third party library, unsurprisingly name [django-compositekey](https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey) that makes it possible to create a model that has a multi column primary key. However that project is not maintained and not compatible with the latest versions of django.

Your best bet, is to add a new column into your table which is a an AutoField and make it the new primary key. The fields that make up the primary key at present can then be marked as [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together). While this may not be ideally for a few queries. It's good enough for most.

If you update your question with the current table structure (as shown in your sql console) I will update my answer to show what the model will look like.

**Update**
There are lots of different ways in which you can drop the old composite primary key and replace it with a new auto increment primary key. Here is the easiest, it involves just SQL

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE newtable DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE newtable ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
RENAME TABLE mytable to mytable_old;
RENAME TABLE newtable to mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable(userid,field1id, rest of the fields) 
    SELECT * FROM mytable_old;
```

Then edit your model and remove the primary_key=True flag from those fields.

**Footnote:**
Some databases like sqlite for example does not support the `LIKE` clause in a `CREATE TABLE`. In these cases, you will have to look up the create table statement for the original table, and copy paste after editing the table name. Judging by your table structure you seem to be using mysql and it supports the `LIKE` clause.

Comment: Is it `pure SQL` though? I'm not sure `LIKE` in `CREATE TABLE` is standard SQL, maybe add change to `pure MySQL` or something like that? (MySQL/MyISAM supports LIKE but Firebird doesn't, not sure about other engines/RDMBSs)

Comment: @JanSegre you are right that it's not supported by all databases. When I was writing pure sql in the above answer i was merely thinking not involving django nd not of the ansi standard. Updating my answer.

Comment: Hi. I have table of 30 million rows. When i drop existing primary keys and add Autofield as primary key, it is taking so much time to query the data.Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: How would this work for foreign keys? If I have a table in my legacy database that references mytable from the example, it would try to reference to the old primary keys, and a lots of Django functions would not work. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score -1):

You must Delete managed = False command from the model to be able to edit your table