# Foreign keys in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Ok so I have a table named Courses where CourseCode and Pattern act as composite primary key. Now in another table called delivery_methods same CourseCode and pattern should act as foreign key for their respective attributes in table Courses. So how can I do that in django model

Comment: You can not have composite primary keys in Django, that is, at the moment, one f the limitations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite primary key in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712848/composite-primary-key-in-django)

Comment: but what about foreign keys. How I can declare CourseCode and Pattern in second table as foreign keys refering to 1st table

Comment: @AmoghKulkarni actually the idea of implementing foreign keys to such composite primary keys are one of the the *main* reasons why they did not implement that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have a composite primary key.
However, what I would do is the following:

Use the default primary key field that django assigns, then set the CourseCode and Pattern to be unique together ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together)). This still will require each database entry to have these two fields as unique together.

You could then use the default primary key as foreign key in the delivery_methods table.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately django does not support composite(compound or multi-column) keys. But, There is a third party library https://django-composite-foreignkey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#example-simple-composite-foreignkey-models for it.
I found several useful links:
https://django-composite-foreignkey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#example-simple-composite-foreignkey-models
[Working with composite primary key in django project with legacy database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248712/working-with-composite-primary-key-in-django-project-with-legacy-database)
https://github.com/onysos/django-composite-foreignkey
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys